# What is 'I' mode in Pillow...?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, rgb, grayscale

I have an image which mode is 'I' (when opened with PIL.Image) and can't understand the concept of 'I' mode.
Pillow explains this mode in a sentence. [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html)

- **'I' mode is 32-bit signed integer pixels**.

So I thought its bit range is very big (about 2 billion) and includes negative numbers. But my image is gray scale and does not have that big numbers.

And it's very confusing that everyone dealing with 'I' mode said their image is gray scale and 16 bit PNG file. No one said 32 bit. I can't find more details about this mode on google.

What I have to do is converting 'I' mode image to 'RGB' mode. PIL has a bug in its convert method [(related issue)](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/5642)
so I need to know about color type and bit depth of an image to manually scale its bits.

I wonder if I can get any clue from the mode itself. (like... 'I' mode image's bit depth is 16 bit or anything else)

And I also want to know why the 'I' came from. Because L mode is for Luminance, P mode is for Palette. So where this 'I' shortened from also can help me.

Comment: Are you sure you have a "I" mode image at beginning? Check the initial image format. It is grayscale, because there is no indication of colours; Just one signed 32-bit integer channel. How to interpret it is up to you. [Why don't you like negative numbers? they are essential for good colour rendering]

Comment: A 32-bit signed integer ranging in value from approximately minus two billion to plus two billion (A signed integer is a 32-bit datum that encodes an integer in the range [-2147483648 to 2147483647].)

Comment: @pippo1980 Oh it's typo thanks for correction.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I guess my image changed to 'I' mode after being photoshoped.  What do you mean by your last sentence? And having one chhenl means grayscale image?

Comment: It is mostly about interpretation (too short to be precise): images -> pixels. Pixel may be composed by different data, each component is a channel (e.g. R,G,B, or Y,Cr,Cb, maybe with also alpha channel). If you say an image has just one channel, one usually interpret it as greyscale (also just 1D). It may be palette (so index of a palette array which describe colours, common in past, usually palettes are max 256 colour lengths). Photoshop has many image format (and internal format use probably half floats).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks for the explanation 

Answer (score 1):

I found the detailed information from their [source code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/7bf5246b93cc89cfb9d6cca78c4719a943b10585/src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py#L693-L708).

Below is a method for getting PNG's IHDR chunk. PIL matches bits depth and color type of png to im_mode and im_rawmode. So 16 bits(2^16) and 1 color type(2^0) means im_mode 'I' and rawmode I;16B. That's why all I saw on google's image were grayscale and 16 bits.

```py
def chunk_IHDR(self, pos, length):
    # image header
    s = ImageFile._safe_read(self.fp, length)     
    self.im_size = i32(s), i32(s[4:])
    try:
        self.im_mode, self.im_rawmode = _MODES[(i8(s[8]), i8(s[9]))]
    except Exception:
        pass
    if i8(s[12]):
        self.im_info["interlace"] = 1
    if i8(s[11]):
        raise SyntaxError("unknown filter category")
    return s
```

```py
_MODES = {
    # supported bits/color combinations, and corresponding modes/rawmodes
    (1, 0):  ("1", "1"),
    (2, 0):  ("L", "L;2"),
    (4, 0):  ("L", "L;4"),
    (8, 0):  ("L", "L"),
    (16, 0): ("I", "I;16B"),
    (8, 2):  ("RGB", "RGB"),
    (16, 2): ("RGB", "RGB;16B"),
    (1, 3):  ("P", "P;1"),
    (2, 3):  ("P", "P;2"),
    (4, 3):  ("P", "P;4"),
    (8, 3):  ("P", "P"),
    (8, 4):  ("LA", "LA"),
    (16, 4): ("RGBA", "LA;16B"),  # LA;16B->LA not yet available
    (8, 6):  ("RGBA", "RGBA"),
    (16, 6): ("RGBA", "RGBA;16B"),
}
```